# Is this default behaviour for instances whose constructor's prototype property is not set to an object?

Tags: javascript

```js
function F() {};
F.prototype = "red";
o = new F();
```

I found it interesting how the above code snippet, when copied in the console, shows that because an object's `[[prototype]]` slot can't be anything other than an object or `null`, `"red"` is unacceptable & `o`'s `[[prototype]]` slot seems to just default to `Object.prototype`. Can I confirm that this is what instances do when their constructor's `.prototype` isn't an object?

(Open to the opinion this is an unpractical question because why would we want to reinitialise a constructor's `.prototype` to something other than an object...but I thought I'd ask anyway just to check).

Comment: Are you asking what happens to an instance when its constructor's prototype is set to something other than an object or `null` _before_ the instance is constructed, or _after_ the instance is constructed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here follows an analysis based on the ECMAScript 2020 specification.

First, it is clear that the `prototype` property can get any value assigned to it. Section [19.2.4.3 prototype](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-function-instances-prototype) mentions no specific restriction:

> Unless otherwise specified, the value of the **"prototype"** property is used to initialize the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the object created when that function is invoked as a constructor.
>
> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]: **false** }.

The process of creating an object via a constructor is specified in section [9.2.2 [[Construct]]](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget). The key action is described in step 5:

> OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(*newTarget*, **"%Object.prototype%"**).

The name specified as second argument is of interest. From section [19.1.2.19 Object.prototype](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype) we learn that this is in fact the name of `Object.prototype` (no surprise).

In section [9.1.13 OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor) we see that this argument is called *IntrinsicDefaultProto*, and step 2 of its procedure depends on [9.1.14 GetPrototypeFromConstructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-getprototypefromconstructor), where we finally get to the core in steps 3 and 4:

> 3. Let *proto* be ? Get(*constructor*, **"prototype"**).
> 4. If Type(*proto*) is not Object, then
>
>    - Let *realm* be ? GetFunctionRealm(*constructor*).
>    - Set *proto* to *realm*'s intrinsic object named *intrinsicDefaultProto*.

So in plain English, this means that if the `prototype` property of the constructor is not an object, then `Object.prototype` will be used instead for defining the prototype object of the newly constructed object.

This also means that if the `prototype` property has value `null`, then still the constructed object will get `Object.prototype` instead of `null` as prototype.

To make an object's prototype `null`, you need to use `Object.create`.

#### Demo

The above can be demonstrated with a little snippet.

```js
function F() {};

// Test 1
F.prototype = "red";
console.log("F.prototype: " + F.prototype); // "red" indeed.
let o = new F;
console.log("Is proto Object.prototype?", 
            Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === Object.prototype); // true

// Test 2
F.prototype = null;
console.log("F.prototype: " + F.prototype); // null indeed.
o = new F;
console.log("Is proto Object.prototype?", 
            Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === Object.prototype); // true

// Test 3
o = Object.create(null);
console.log("Is proto of Object.create(null) null?", 
            Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === null); // true
```

Comment: Nothing to add. (Except maybe it's worth mentioning that "*Type(proto) is Object*" also includes functions, arrays, regexes, proxies and everything that is not a primitive value.)